# How to save latitude, longitude in my db. Using leaflet map

Tags: javascript, mongodb, leaflet

I am building an app that uses leaflet map and mongoDB as my db. I want the user to be able to click on a place on the map and edit the details on the marker and then i want to save these places on my db. How do i do that? I am relatively new and i have to do this for my diploma thesis and i have no previous experience with databases and javascript.
I have already setup my db using mongoose.

I searched on stackorverflow for a similar question but i couldn't find anything new, if i just missed it, please redirect me there.

Thanks!

Comment: `How do i do that?` with which specific part of that process do you have problems? Reading the lat/lng from the marker? Passing the data from the UI (browser, electron, …?) to the code that is able to connect to the database (nodejs, electron backend, …?), or is your problem how to to pass the received data to the database? You need to be more specific with which exact part of this process you have problems, as each of it is a separate topic.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i have a problem passing the data to the database. Leaflet lets you click on the map and there is a popup with the lat/lng so then you can edit what the popup says and then i don't know how to save the lat/lng and the edited information on the marker to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Saving data into the database.

```
// 1. make a mongoose model
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: "Placeholder Location Name"
  },
  coordinates: {
    type: [Number],
    default: [0, 0]
  }
});
const Location = mongoose.model('Location', schema);

// 2. example of making a Location
const exampleLocation = new Location({
  name: "My First Location",
  coordinates: [41.40338, 2.17403] // This is where your example coordinates go.
})

exampleLocation.save((err) => {
  if (err) console.log("An error occured while trying to save: " + err)
  else console.log("Success") // the object is saved
})
```

Capturing a click on the map

```
let map = document.getElementById('your-leaflet-map-id')

map.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  console.log('The clicked coordinates were: ' + event.latlng.lat + ',' + event.latlng.lng)
  // feel free to use these coordinates as you wish
  yourMethodToSaveLocation(event.latlng.lat, event.latlng.lng)
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the connection between the code and the locations that someone clicks on the map. 
For example, I created a users collection in my db and if I go and press the button "add a user" then the user gets added and I understand the relationship between the code and the app because I created all this. But now I can't understand how the relationship between something I did not create and "just exists" on my app (like the map and whatever I click on it) and the code for saving *this* to the db. Sorry for my english I hope it makes sense.

Comment: It is always best to read the documentation made by the developers that created the technology you are using. You need to capture a click event on the map by creating an event listener. The map component will provide the appropriate information to the event object as stated here in the leaflet map documentation: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#mouseevent-latlng

I have added an example of capturing location data of a click in the answer.